# Convex optimization when the min is minus infinity

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, logistic-regression

I am new to convex optimization and I understand that when the function is convex, it is very easy to find the minimum since no matter where we start, we will always go down to the minimum. But what if that minimum is minus infinity, for example the convex function `exp(-x)` for x in R and the loss function of logistic regresion, how do we handle these situations?

Comment: Your understanding is oversimplified and incorrect.  It's simply not true that a minimum is attained for every convex minimization problem.  There are a variety of conditions that do ensure that a minimum will be attained.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).